# Parallax Freeze Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a beautiful parallax cap of 6 png images.
But the page freezes terribly for 10 seconds and only then starts to work normally.
If you go to another tab and go back, then again the whole tab freezes for 5 seconds.
Why can this happen?

Friezes are observed on two different PCs with good power. Even if the music from the browser works and open a contribution with this parallax, the music slows down 2 times and starts to lag: D

```css
body {
    background-color: #271c33;
}

.art-block {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
}

.art-block, .art_layer {
    height: 1000px;
}

.art_layer {
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-size: auto 1038px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.art_layer.parallax {
    position: fixed;
}
    
#art-back {
    background-image: url(../img/background-min.jpg);
}

#art-1 {
    background-image: url(../img/1-min.png);
}

#art-2 {
    background-image: url(../img/2-min.png);
}

#art-3 {
    background-image: url(../img/3-min.png);
}

#art-4 {
    background-image: url(../img/4-min.png);
}

#art-5 {
    background-image: url(../img/5-min.png);
}

#art-6 {
    background-image: url(../img/6-min.png);
}

.main {
    background-color: #271c33;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/util.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?1582535292">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="art-block">
            <div class="art_layer parallax" id="art-back" data-speed="2"></div>
            <div class="art_layer parallax" id="art-6" data-speed="7"></div>
            <div class="art_layer parallax" id="art-5" data-speed="22"></div>
            <div class="art_layer parallax" id="art-4" data-speed="33"></div>
            <div class="art_layer parallax" id="art-3" data-speed="46"></div>
            <div class="art_layer parallax" id="art-2" data-speed="58"></div>
            <div class="art_layer" id="art-1" data-speed="55"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="main" style="height: 2500px;">
            ss
        </div>
        
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).scroll(function(){
             var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
             
             $('.art_layer.parallax').each(function(){
              var $layer = $(this);
              var yPos = -(windowScroll * $layer.data('speed') / 100);
              $layer.css({
               "transform" : "translate3d(0px, " + yPos + "px, 0px)"
              });
            
             });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image: Inspector Screenshot]

May be image sizes? 7000x3500 pixels

Comment: Can you please put your code in "stack overflow snippet" or "JS fiddle".

Comment: Issue i wither with Loading of More data on tab change event or using large size image as you mention the dimension `7000x3500px` so make sure its size is in `kbs` not `Mbs`